# Android Including XML files = where to put them

Tags: android, xml, resources

I am developing an app that needs to refer to data in a number of XML files. There are a lot ( ~40) XML files required by the app.

The file have names like "AbnormalFlags-v1.0.xml" and I current have them located in

> res/raw/v2/AbnormalFlags-v1.0.xml
>   res/raw/v2/ActualDeliveryPlace-v1.0.xml
>   res/raw/v2/AddressType-v1.0.xml ... ...

A number of questions

- Is this the best place to locate these files ?
- The filenames seem to be a problem, will that cause issues
- Because I have to dynamically determine which file to use I use the:

  `xmlFile = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(xmlFileId,"raw","com.apps4health.refpack");`

This does not find the resource file, where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the format of the file names I would suggest you to save them in the `assets` folder. Create a folder named `assets` inside the `res` folder and put there the XML files.

The code below shows how to open files in the `assets` directory:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
   AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
   is = am.open("AbnormalFlags-v1.0.xml");
   // Process the XML file from "is"...
}catch( IOException e ) { 
   // Handle exception
}
```

[AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) is responsible to open files saved in the `res/assets` folder. You just call the `open()` method passing the file name as argument.